# confusion passing data to pthread_create()... how it works?

Tags: pthreads

Please take a look to the `pthread_create()` prototype we have:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

to the last argument is a void pointer. But taking a look in some code in the internet I see developers doing:

```
long t;
pthread_create( &thread, NULL, function, (void*)t);
```

and it works!!! I mean they are not doing:

```
pthread_create( &thread, NULL, function, (void*)&t);
```

in other words, the reference of "t" is not being used.

However, if I change the datatype to "int" instead "long".. does not work.

I believe the reference should be considered always but do you have idea why long is working with no references?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter being passed to the thread function is a `void*`.  In the general case, that pointer can point to some block of data the function can use.

However, remember that the pointer itself is a value. It's common to simply use that value as the data for the thread function if the amount of data you're passing is small enough to fit in a `void*` - namely if all you need to pass to the function is a integer value.  That's what's happening the case:

```
long t;

t = /* some value to pass to the thread */;

pthread_create( &thread, NULL, function, (void*)t);
```

One advantage to this is that you don't have lifetime issues to deal with on the thread data.

Comment: But then why wouldn't the same thing work wit `int`?  If `long` is small enough to fit into `void*`, shouldn't `int` also be so?

Comment: @Shredderroy - we'd have to see specific code to say what the difference is - I suspect that it's something to do with sign extension that is or isn't happening because of the specific way casts to/from the `void*` are coded.

Comment: My initial thought, when I read the question, was that the value of `long` was perhaps implicitly being recognised as an address, but the value of `int` was not.  But I wasn't sure.  Moreover, it seems that my thought would be implementation- or compiler-specific, whereas the original poster seems to intend this as a general occurrence.

Comment: There are definitely implementation-specific details that need to be considered, since the relative sizes of `void*`, `int`, and `long` are different on different implementations.  That is likely the reason for `int` 'not working', while `long` does.

Comment: guys thank you for all responses.. I was reading in different forums about this.. they are saying to avoid the usage of references because each thread operates in a own context and passing as references the threads may have conflicts using the same pointer.. however, if I need to pass a integer using a struct, even using a struct (multiples data), I still can have internal pointers on those structures.. Actually the fact of works or not, I believe it is related to aligment and sizes.. not sure if works in embedded system with different processors like arm, core8, etc.

Comment: @user1657666: if you pass a pointer (references don't exist in C) to data to the thread(s), you need to take care of several things, including that the lifetime of the object extends long enough and that each thread gets its own copy if necessary. For example, if the data is only read by the threads and can be the same for each thread, then there's no need for separate copies - but that's a pretty unusual scenario.  If you're passing a pointer to data, alignment isn't an issue any more that it would be for passing a pointer to something to a function in the same thread.